# Smart Table event beforeRebindTable calling only when view loads in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I am facing issue with the smart table event **beforeRebindTable** here iam having a smart table in view2 based on some selection on view1 we need to navigate to view2 and bind data to the smart table where iam writing my code in beforeRebindTable event, for the first time it is working fine, but when we navigate to view1 and again selecting some value in view1 and navigate to view2 then beforeRebindTable event is not triggering.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After navigating to the 2nd page, you should call #rebindTable method in order to trigger that event.

If you are using sap.ui.core.routing class for navigation, then you can do it in 'routePatternMatched' event.